# Array Reduce or similar

Tags: arrays, go, reduce

I have an array:

```
const assets = [{
  type: 'X',
  value: 322.12
}, {
  type: 'X',
  value: 413.21
}]
```

I want the sum of values (735,33)

In node.js I can use: `const sum = assets.reduce((s, val) => ( s = s + val.value), 0)`

How can I do the same in Go?

Comment: Use a [for](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) loop to sum the values: `var s int; for _, asset := range assets { s += asset.value }`.  Loops are covered in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1).

Comment: `reduce` is actually a method on js Arrays, and it didn't implement on the go arrays. Although you shouldn't expect functional language properties on go either. Go is used to be simple and in order to do such a `reduce` thing you have to use a simple for.
But if you really insist to use that style, you can also define your own array type in go and write a `reduce` method for id :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/Bp6r7CN-p_X) is an incomplete implementation, but it gives you an idea of why this is a bad idea and non-idiomatic Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Array []int

type ReducerFn func(prev int, next int) int

func (arr Array) Reduce(fn ReducerFn, i int) int {
    prev := i
    for _, v := range arr {
        prev = fn(prev, v)
    }
    return prev
}

func main() {
    i := Array([]int{1,2,4})
    fmt.Println(i.Reduce(func(prev int, next int) int { 
        return prev + next
    }, 10))
}
```

Since there are no generics in Go, you'll have to create a different reducer method for every return type, which might be quite impractical.

See also [Francesc Campoy's talk at dotGo2015, "Functional Go?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouyHp2nJl0I).

Answer (score 2):

I would *go* with [Modf()](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Modf)

```golang
i = 0
f = 0
for _, asset := range assets {
    integer, frac := Modf(asset.value)
    i += integer
    f += math.Round(frac*100)/100))
}
fmt.Println(i, f)
```